# Combine multiple excel files

Tags: r, excel

I am writing code in which I have multiple google trends data frames and I wish to export all of these into a combined excel file.

Example of code I am working with:

```
Data1 <- Gtrends(keyword = keyword, geo = geo…..)

Data2 <- gtrends(keyword = …)

Data3 <- gtrends(keyword =…)
```

The data sets all have the information (same time, same search terms, same country), all that is different is the county in which data is being pulled.

I need to export all of this into one excel file. Thank you!

I have all of my data sets being written into individual excel files right now but need to either combine from the data frame level or the excel file level

Answer (score 0):

You can save all datasets as one big table or separate tables on excel sheets.

### Combine datasets into one dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(writexl)

bind_rows(
  Data1,
  Data2,
  Data3) |>
write_xlsx(path = "filename.xlsx")
```

### Save each dataset on a separate excel sheet

```
library(writexl)

write_xlsx(list(Data1 = Data1,
                Data2 = Data2,
                Data3 = Data3),
           path = "filename2.xlsx")
```